# document.referrer not coming when open a link from stackoveflow

Tags: javascript

we want to track link.

for eg : http://yellow.live

we are not receiving any referrer when open it through stackoverflow

Comment: Browsers are not allowed to send referrer when going from https to http ([spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links on StackOverflow get the nofollow and noreferrer `rel` value which means that bots won't follow the link and when you click it, a referrer is not passed.

If you want to track a click, add a [tracking parameter](https://www.launchdigitalmarketing.com/what-are-utm-codes/) to the url.